# Angular Deleting a column from a list

Tags: angular, types

I am trying to delete a column from a list and before deleting I am keeping the list assigned to another list for backup. But after deleting the colmun from the list that column in the backup list also gets removed.

```
 this.commonService
  .fetchContractByDate(this.authService.loggedUser.companyId, this.startDate, this.endDate)
  .subscribe((response: any) => {
    const clientName = this.clients;

    this.contractListbyClient = response.data;
    this.allList = response.data;
    this.forexport(clientName, contractList);

    for (const contract of this.contractListbyClient) {
      for (const selected of this.selection.selected) {
        if (selected.name === 'startDate' || selected.name === 'endDate') {
          contract[selected.display] = this.commonService.getFormattedDate(contract[selected.name]);
        } else {
          contract[selected.display] = contract[selected.name];
        }
      }

      for (const item of this.columns) {
        delete contract[item.name];
      }
    }
```

In the above code the selected columns from the **this.contractListbyClient** gets removed , But the same changes gets reflected in the  **this.allList** as well. can any one tell me how can I keep a copy of list unchanged

Answer (score 0):

This is because for objects the value of the variable is a reference. Because of this, when you pass an object and change its members, those changes persist outside of the function. This makes it look like pass by reference.

To solve this problem we should correctly clone that object, one easy way of doing is below:

```
 this.contractListbyClient = response.data;
 this.allList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`this.contractListbyClient = Object.assign({}, response.data);
 this.allList = Object.assign({}, response.data);`